# Necessary condition for the integral equation $u(x) = f(x)+\lambda\int K(x,t)u(t)dt$ to have a continuous solution?

Tags: integration

Is the following condition necessary for the integral equation $$u(x) = f(x)+\lambda\int K(x,t)u(t)dt$$  to have a continuous solution: $f(x) \neq 0$, is real and continuous in the interval $[a,b]$?

When $f(x) = 0$, the integral equation will become homogeneous. So I think this should be a necessary condition.  Am I right? Please suggest me

Comment: Are there any limits on the integral? What do you know about $K$?

Comment: limits are from a to b and K is kernel of of fredholm integral equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would $f$ have to be nonzero or real? If $f = 0$ there is certainly a continuous solution, namely $0$.  There may be nonzero solutions as well.  You'll probably want to assume $K(x, \cdot)$ to be in $L^1(a,b)$ so the
integral exists for all $u \in C[a,b]$.  Then under some conditions on $K$ (e.g. if $K$ is continuous) $\int_a^b K(x,t) u(t)\ dt$ will be continuous for all continuous $u$.
If so, $f(x) = u(x) - \lambda \int_a^b K(x,t) u(t)\ dt$ will have to be continuous in order for there to be a continuous solution, and will have to be real if $K$ is real and there is a real solution.

Comment: I have a doubt. In fredholm equation, if we solve the equation by successive iteration then we need $K$ to be $L^2$ function. If we solve the equation by successive substitution then we need just boundedness of $K$. In both cases we need continuity of K. What should be the minimum case for the integral equation be well posed?

Answer (score -1):

It has a unique continuous solution.It's solution is given by Lioville-Neumann Series.
          http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville-Neumann_series

Comment: OK thanks sir. but i want to know whether the condition mentioned above is necessary or not. i think it is but not sure.

Comment: Under appropriate conditions on $K$, the series will converge to a unique continuous solution for sufficiently small $|\lambda|$.  It may not converge for all $\lambda$, and there may be $\lambda$ for which there is no solution or a nonunique solution.